# Customizing Drupal Commerce Bundle module

Tags: commerce

How can I customize Drupal Commerce Bundle module? My situation is that I am developing an Ecommerce site where user can buy Necklaces from necklace collection and lockets from locket collection, both combined to form a single product. So I have used commerce bundle module to achieve this. Now I am stuck in an issue which is what if the user wants to buy multiple lockets or multiple necklaces? Currently the user have the option to select only one of each type to form a single product. How can I achieve multiple selection?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC you may have better results using Commerce Product Add-on, which allows you to have other products as add-ons. Product Bundles work well when you have fixed bundles - i.e. "A fork, spade, and bucket", not "Forks", "Spades", and "Buckets" you want to cross/upsell - if you know what I mean...!

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pado

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment.  I have used Commerce Product Add-on as you have suggested and achieved the preferred result except that the products are added to cart each individually. The cart is showing each component product seperately. Is there anyway that  the main product and selected add ons are added as a bundle to cart?